# Interact with OAuth secured api from gnome shell extension

Tags: api, calendar, gnome, gnome-shell-extensions

I would like to show a bunch of my google calendar tasks on my desktop using a gnome shell extension. I just went over how the quickstart that explains how to use the api normally over at https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python. That seems to require the user to click a specific button every time the application requests access to that users's calendar.
I want to call the api from a gnome shell extension, where preferrably I only get some kind of security key once, and cache it so that i can use it for all subsequent requests. How can i make this happen (with GJS, since it's an extension)?